# Meaning of printf("%c", **++argv);?

Tags: c

What is the meaning of:

```
printf("%c", **++argv);
```

in a C command line program?

Comment: First character of second argument.

Comment: where did you read code like this?

Comment: The question is not answerable without knowing the declaration of `argv`. Ok, it might be obvious (in this special) case what you are talking about, but anyway ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might declare `argv` in main(): 
like = `main(int argc, char** argv)`

`argv` is string of arguments string.

```
++argv means (argv + 1)
```

`*` is value at address operator:

So

`*argv` => `*(argv + 0)` => `argv[0]` points 0th argument that is **program name**
`*(argv +1)` => `argv[1]` points to `1th argument` that should be passed on command like.

`*++argv  => *(argv + 1)` =>  `argv[1]`  that is first argument's address,

**[ANSWER]**

`**++argv  => *(*(argv + 1) )`  => `*(*(argv + 1) + 0)` => `*((argr[1] + 0)` => `argv[1][0]` that is first char of first argument.

Comment: To Grijesh Chauhan:I think it will be first char of second argument because argv[0] is program name.

Comment: @ManojitGhosh  Yes argv[0] is program name

Answer (score 7):

Print the first character of the first argument passed. i.e. `argv[1][0]`

`argv` is a pointer to pointer passed to `main()`.

`**++argv`:

First it is incremented (due to pre-increment) to point to the next pointer which is`argv[1]` and then dereferences that pointer to pointer using which is `argv[1][0]`.

Comment: Will you please explain how?

Comment: What could be the answer for ```**+argv```?

Comment: @KavinRajuS That's invalid: unary `+` requires the operand to be an arithmetic type whereas `argv` is a pointer type.

Answer (score 0):

This prints the first character of the first command line argument when executing the program or crashes (by de-referencing a null pointer) if the program were run without an argument.

*(++argv) returns argv[1]

which is the first argument string or null (if no argument is passed to the program)

*( *(++argv) ) is *argv[1] = argv[1][0]

which is the first character of the first argument (if there is one) or otherwise *(null), which would crash.

Answer (score 0):

In routine `main()` parameter `argv` is used as array of strings, i.e. `argv` is a pointer to a pointer to a character. "`++argv`" auto-increments to point to the second commandline argument passed to `main()`. `*++argv` is the pointer to the first character in the second argument, and finally `**++argv` is the first character of the seconds argument itself as posted by cnicutar.

In `printf` "`%c`" is used as placeholder for a parameter of type character.

Answer (score 0):

Here comes the concept of command line arguments..

Command line arguments are the arguments passed to main function..

```
printf("%c",**++argv);
```

prints the first character of the first argument after the executable..

The above statement executes as per precedence.. First the argument is incremented and then dereferenced to get the value..